# I can't connect to my server over the internet

Tags: c#, networking, sockets

I can run the server on my local machine and connect to it on the same machine, but when I try to connect to it from a different computer over the internet, there is not sign of activity on my server, nor a response from the server on the computer I'm testing it on. I've tried both XP and Vista, turn off firewalls, opened ports, ran as admin; nothing is working. :(

**Here is my code that I'm using to accept an incoming connection:**

```
int port = 3326;
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
                listener.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Server established\nListening on Port: {0}\n", port);
                while (true)
                {
                    socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
                    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, outime);
                    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
                    socket.DontFragment = true;
                    NewConnection pxy = new NewConnection(socket);
                    Thread client = new Thread(new ThreadStart(pxy.Start));
                    client.IsBackground = true;
                    client.Start();
                }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that the problem is in your router, not your computer. When packets come from the Internet, it should be routed to an specific server. You have to configure your router to redirect the traffic on port `3326` to your server.

Answer (score 3):

You've probably got something blocking the connection higher up. Try connecting from another host on the LAN. If you can do that, then the OS itself isn't firewalling the connection.

If either you or your ISP run a NAT router, then your machine probably doesn't have a publicly accessible address, in which case it's impossible to connect directly to it.

If there is no NAT router, something may still be blocking the connection upstream.

Comment: i can connect via a different host on the LAN, am i able to use my router to port forward to the server machine. I remember a while ago i hosted a VOIP server - Teamspeak and ventrilo on my LAN which was accessible via internet, can i do something similar with this?

Answer (score 0):

**I am serious:** Many ISPs actively work to *stop* you from using your home connection as a web server. You might want to call them before you invest too much time.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to host at home, your ISP may be restricting you.